# Get node name within DDS network

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently extracting some information from the ROS network by the use of the FastDDS Statistic module ( https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/statistics/statistics.html ). However I'm not able to extract/retrieve the node names as defined in the ROS network. The nodes are only visible as DDS entities whereby I can manually extrapolate the name by seeing the associated topics, however I would like for this to happen automatically.

This is the information I'm able to extract:

```
 {
   "alias":"/",
   "alive":true,
   "guid":"01.0f.3b.dd.c9.08.6f.31.01.00.00.00|0.0.1.c1",
   "id":6,
   "kind":"participant",
   "locators":[
      "UDPv4:[127.0.0.1]:7414",
      "UDPv4:[127.0.0.1]:7415"
   ],
   "metatraffic":false,
   "name":"/",
   "qos":{
      "available_builtin_endpoints":3135,
      "lease_duration":{
         "nanoseconds":0,
         "seconds":20
      },
      "properties":[
         {
            "name":"PARTICIPANT_TYPE",
            "value":"SIMPLE"
         }
      ],
      "user_data":"656e636c6176653d2f3b0",
      "vendor_id":[
         1,
         15
      ]
   }
}
```

The name is always listed as "/". Is there a way to map this information?

Kind regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393229/get-node-name-within-dds-network/) by [Gintecc](https://answers.ros.org/users/91581/gintecc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS nodes do not have a direct parallel in DDS. DDS deals only with topics, it has no externally-visible awareness of the entities that are publishing or subscribing to those topics. Internally, DDS has a concept of participants, which are objects that publish and subscribe to topics, but there is no equivalence relationship between a DDS participant and a ROS node any more (it used to be a 1-to-1 mapping, but now there is only one DDS participant per process and it is possible to have multiple nodes in a single process).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1